# why is my async file upload returning a 404 not found?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following script in my asp.net webform page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function uploadStarted() {
            $get("imgDisplay").style.display = "initial";
        }
        function uploadComplete(sender, args) {
            var imgDisplay = $get("imgDisplay");
            imgDisplay.src = "../Images/Pictures/loader.gif";
            imgDisplay.style.cssText = "";
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function () {
                imgDisplay.style.cssText = "height:120px;width:100px";
                imgDisplay.src = img.src;
            };
            img.src = "<%=ResolveUrl("~/Images/") %>" + args.get_fileName();
            }
    </script>
```

and the following code in my aspx.cs file:

```
 protected void AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
        {
            if (AsyncFileUpload1.HasFile) 
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(AsyncFileUpload1.FileName);
                string ext = fi.Extension;
                string fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
                AsyncFileUpload1.SaveAs(fileName);
            }
        }
```

what i'm trying to achieve is to upload an image to the server and get the uploaded image name to display the file before the client saves it. however i get a 404 error because it is rather reading the name of the image selected on the client machine instead of the one on the server.

What am I doing wrong in my code?? and how do I solve this issue?

Comment: You *do* ask for the client-side name in the callback. Your javascript callback only knows about the *Javascript* operation, it doesn't know that you intend to rename the file on the server *after* the upload finishes (in the Upload*Complete* event).

Comment: how do i rewrite my code to get the server name then? @PanagiotisKanavos